# Which server & client options are needed to create an OpenVPN "Remote Access" i.e. "Client-to-Site" VPN, without routing all traffic through the VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

## the goal & issue

I have tried *very* hard to solve this, but I'm stuck.  I'm not looking to create a site-to-site VPN, for reference.

I have successfully installed OpenVPN using ansible: https://github.com/BastiPaeltz/ansible-openvpn (required quite a few patches to get it to work with python3 and the latest easyrsa version plus fixing a couple bugs).

I am successfully pushing the route of my AWS VPC (`172.31.0.0/16`) to clients, and they can connect to hosts in that network, but this ceases to work when I configure them to not route all their traffic through the VPN (i.e, not redirect their gateway).

What do I need to do to preserve remote access to my VPC, but not have clients redirect their gateways? I am really struggling to decipher the OpenVPN documentation. There is no straightforward example of how to set up a simple remote access vpn that I've found, but maybe it's there an I missed it due to lack of experience with this.

## configs:

`server.conf`:

NOTE: commenting out `push "redirect-gateway def1"` does not fix the issue.

```
dev tun-udp-1194

server 10.9.80.0 255.255.240.0

proto udp

port 1194



ca /etc/openvpn/pki/ca.crt

cert....

key ...

dh /etc/openvpn/pki/dh.pem

crl-verify /etc/openvpn/pki/crl.pem



#push "redirect-gateway def1"



route 172.31.0.0 255.255.0.0



# Fix for the Windows 10 DNS leak described here:

# https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/605

push block-outside-dns



remote-cert-tls client

keepalive 10 120

tls-auth /etc/openvpn/pki/ta.key 0

cipher AES-256-CBC

tls-cipher TLS-DHE-DSS-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256:TLS-DHE-DSS-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256

auth SHA256

tls-version-min 1.2

comp-lzo

persist-key

persist-tun

verb 0
```

`client.conf`:

NOTE adding `pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway` breaks the VPN entirely, and I can't access the VPC; commenting out `redirect-gateway def1` does nothing.

```
client

remote <my_ip> 1194 udp

# route all traffic through the VPN (comment out to prevent routing

# all traffic through the VPN, and retain your router's public IP, etc)

#redirect-gateway def1



# ignore any redirect-gateway configs pushed from the server; breaks the VPN

#pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway



dev tun

cipher AES-256-CBC

auth SHA256

resolv-retry infinite

nobind

persist-key

persist-tun

remote-cert-tls server

verify-x509-name "<dns_name>" name

tls-version-min 1.2

comp-lzo

key-direction 1

verb 3
```

These are the `iptables` rules I've configured on the server, via this script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Generated by ansible
# This script is used to configure iptables to work with OpenVPN on this host

# Allow connections to the VPN
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT

# This rule is necessary for OpenVPN to work and forward IP packets
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.9.80.0/20 -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE

/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.9.80.0/20 -j ACCEPT

# Allow SSH connections on the VPN
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 10.9.80.0/20 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

The output is below.

```
root@ip-172-31-38-0:/etc/openvpn# iptables -n -L
```

> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
> target     prot opt source               destination
> ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:1194
> ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.9.80.0/20         tcp dpt:22

> Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
> target     prot opt source               destination
> ACCEPT     all  --  10.9.80.0/20         0.0.0.0/0

> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
> target     prot opt source               destination

```
root@ip-172-31-38-0:/etc/openvpn# iptables -t nat -n -L
```

> target     prot opt source               destination

> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
> target     prot opt source               destination

> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
> target     prot opt source               destination

> Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
> target     prot opt source               destination
> MASQUERADE  all  --  10.9.80.0/20         0.0.0.0/0

Any help in the form of actual configuration would be greatly appreciated; thanks.

Comment: `route 172.31.0.0 255.255.0.0` when placed in the server conf should be a pushed value. Or place it in the client conf.

Comment: @TomYan, thanks, this was correct; much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The summary is "push routes (and other options) you want and don't push routes you don't want", there is really nothing more than that.

- To avoid redirecting all traffic, do not push the `redirect-gateway` option, as that's exactly what it does – it's just a default route.

  If removing that option breaks something else, it doesn't necessarily mean you needed the option – rather, often it means something else is missing and the 'redirect-gateway' option merely covered for the missing one.
- Specifically, your current server configuration *does not* push the 172.31.0.0/16 route to clients – it remains server-side only, and all of it only worked because 'redirect-gateway' covered up for the lack of specific routes. You need to use `push "route ..."` to have that route deployed to clients.
- On a related note, if you find yourself reaching for 'pull-filter' to prevent clients from pulling something unneeded, instead change the server configuration to not push that something in the first place.

Comment: thanks! I deleted the `route..` on the server side, and replaced it with the `push "route..."`, and all worked well.